# How do I back up from gitlab.com

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd like a simple way to backup my private repositories from Gitlab.com. I'm fairly new to Git so apologies if this is a RTFM question.

I've seen rake tasks discussed for backing up gitlab self hosted installations but wasn't sure if these could be used with the Gitlab.com hosted service.

Comment: As the topmost answer suggests; this question requires more specifics - what do you want to back up, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to back-up the code and history?

In that case, a simple

```
git clone <url>
```

will do the trick. Git is distributed (see e.g. [Why git is called a distributed source control system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212740/why-git-is-called-a-distributed-source-control-system)), so you will have a local copy of your entire repository.

Answer (score 1):

The new GitLab 8.9 release has an Import/Export feature. It's documented here: [Project import/export](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/settings/import_export.html).

> The following items will be exported:
>
> - Project and wiki repositories
> - Project uploads
> - Project configuration including web hooks and services
> - Issues with comments, merge requests with diffs and comments, labels, milestones, snippets, and other project entities
>
> The following items will NOT be exported:
>
> - Build traces and artifacts
> - LFS objects